# Query from HashMaps

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

Please I need to query from the an Integer Value (AtomicInteger) from the Inner HashMap of a Multidimensional HashMap. I need to know what LocalStore has a copy of a game in stock. I have the inStock HashMap seperate... Here is the code on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/tQZ09Jha)...

Please I need help on how to proceed!

Comment: For the complete class files, visit http://pastebin.com/16WrZmYw

Comment: The file I have is like this:

Assasin's Creed [Store 3] Delaware 15

Assasin's Creed [Store 4] Manchester 23

Assasin's Creed [Store 5] Osasuna 10

Fifa09 [Store 1] Adelaide 0

Fifa09 [Store 2] Barcelona 3
Fifa09 [Store 3] Delaware 0
Fifa09 [Store 4] Manchester 7
Fifa09 [Store 5] Osasuna 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to iterate over the `inStock` Map. If you don't have hundreds or thousands of stores the performance will be fine.

```
public static List<LocalStore> checkInStock(String gameTitle) {
   return checkInStock(new Game(gameTitle));
}

public static List<LocalStore> checkInStock(Game g) {
    List<LocalStores> stores = new ArrayList<LocalStores>();
    for (Map.Entry<LocalStore, HashMap<Game, AtomicInteger>> entry : inStock.entrySet()) {
      HashMap<Game, AtomicInteger> tmp = entry.getValue();
      AtomicInteger anInt = tmp.get(g);
      if (anInt != null && anInt.get() > 0) {
        stores.add(entry.getKey());
      }
    }
    return stores;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.

Remember the value of the 'inStock' HashMap should be the inner HashMap. Of you mean it will just be one value for both HashMaps? That way I am confused. Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: You're right. Didn't want to confuse you - I got lost here. Updated the code. Better?

Comment: So I should have something like...

 'static void checkStock(Games g)' as the argument and the first line of the code can go? and make the fourth line 'AtomicInteger' instead of 'Integer'

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer and added a method to search by the title of a game as String. And yes it's AtomicInteger :) . . . not my day

Comment: Hi Martin, WHen I ran this, It did not give me the expected output. Also please let this be your day oh... Cos I must make submission today... within the next 9 hours

Comment: The problem here is that the stores ArrayList does not populate. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Hello, I noticed AtomicInteger anInt = tmp.get(g); is returning a null value... Anything m getting wrong?

Comment: I now used Integer instead of AtomicInteger and I am getting it. Thanks. You are the Best! And please rate my research effort.

Comment: Just went online. Glad to hear you're fine. The reason you were getting null upon 'tmp.get(game)', was that nobody did 'tmp.put(game, new Integer(0)' before. For that reason I added the check for 'null' in the 'if' and handled 'null' as '0'. You received an upvote. Good luck with the assignment! :)

Comment: Hello Martin, I just noticed while populating the HashMap, something else is going wrong... I cant just phantom what it is. Can you please help check? I have limited time please

Comment: Most especially populating the inner one with the outer one. It seems it needs to be cleared or so because it keeps bringing out/mapping same one

Comment: Also, in both maps... inStock and stockMap what decides the real Key

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fESbnrYY Post is public you can create/edit/version it

Comment: Can I get the key from the Hashmap given the value?

Comment: By iterating over the entries 'map.entrySet()' until found. Or map it 'reverse' by creating a second map. HashMap/java.util.Map itself doesn't have a - say - reverse mapping. Hey, that's actually a whole 'question' ;)

Comment: After following the pastebin code, i got this as my output... { Delaware={},  Adelaide={},  Osasuna={},  Barcelona={},  Manchester={}} as the final content of inStock map

Comment: I have a new paste. Kindly visit http://pastebin.com/v3U50axY

Comment: Hi Martin,  I am trying to get the IntegerValue of the Game in the checkInStock(Games g) class by declaring another  AtomicInteger anINT = new AtomicInteger(0); and then adding anINT.addAndGet(anInt.intValue()); in the if statement but it is giving me a wrong data value as the anINT against what I am supposed to get